# Drop all columns from table in Rails migration

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-migration, rails-migrations

Say in Rails 3, you have a model `User` and hence its table is called `:users`

Something went horribly wrong and you need to drop the table but you cannot since you have other references to the `user_id`. So you need to clear your `users` table schema.

Basically what you need is a way to drop all columns.

If your table has more than 40 columns, you can forget the style

```
remove_column :users, :col1
```

You need to do it all at once. In one migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have generated a blank migration using

`rails g migration PurgeOldUsersSchema`

So this is how your migration should look like

```
class PurgeOldUsersSchema < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    cols = []
    User.columns.collect(&:name).each do |col|
     cols.push(col.to_sym)
    end
    cols = cols - [:id]
    remove_column :users, cols
  end
end
```

Keep in mind the `- [:id]` is necessary since rails cannot allow you to drop the primary key. In this array you can add any column name you want to preserve post the purge op.

This keeps your references to this table intact in the schema, but you would anyway purge the data, so that is not much relevant. :-)

**UPDATE**

Have tried this solution but `remove_column :users, cols` didn't work for me so I had to replace it with:

```
cols.each { |col| remove_column :users, col }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=XXX` in the terminal and it should remove all data on the Users table.

And then run: `rake db:migrate`